# not able to add the key value pair properly in JSON object

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, json

I am trying to add key value pair in the below JSON object, but it is getting added in the wrong way, is there any way i can add to each object a new  key value pair, that will help me to complete the req.

JSON as follow :

```
var object =[
      {
         "asdf":"",
         "fdrtf":"869966",
         "hdhfhfh":"utytut",
         "Cat":"A"
         
      },
      {
         "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B"
         
      },
      {
         "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B"
      }
]

code i am using to add the new key value pair :
for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
            object[i]['ABC'] = [i];
        }
```

Actually expected should be:

```
var object =[
      {
         "asdf":"",
         "fdrtf":"869966",
         "hdhfhfh":"utytut",
         "Cat":"A",
         "ABC": "0"
         
      },
      {
         "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B",
         "ABC": "1"
         
      },
      {
         "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B"
         "ABC": "2"
      }
]
```

the final value i am getting as below:

```
["0":{
         "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B",
      
   },
   "1":{
         "asdf":"",
         "fdrtf":"869966",
         "hdhfhfh":"utytut",
         "Cat":"A"
         
   },
   "2":{
       "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B"
   }
  ]
```

kindly someone help me out to achieve this

Comment: Please do not repost questions or post under multiple accounts. If you need to make changes, you can [edit] a post.

Comment: Additionally, because this question has no specificity to Salesforce, Stack Overflow or introductory JavaScript resources such as the Mozilla Developer Network are likely to be the best help.

Comment: I am trying this in lwc of salesforcr

Answer (score 2):

The `= [i]` is what's causing the problem, at least in part. However, this isn't very JavaScript-y; you simply use Array.prototype.map instead:

```
object = object.map((value,index) => ({ ...value, ABC: index }));
```

Here we use Array.prototype.map, which uses a callback function to determine what the new value should be based on the old value. `(params) => ({...}))` is an arrow function. `{...value}` copies the old values to a new object (shallow copy) so we can work on the data, and then we assign the new property as well (`, ABC: index`).

Comment: do i need to add inside the for loop ,,,sorry but didn't understand..

Comment: i tried inside the for loop but still getting the same result

Comment: @Rukmina No, the for loop is not necessary at all.

Comment: getting this error :  [e.map is not a function] without loop

Comment: @Rukmina No idea what you did wrong. This is need correct, you use the map function for this purpose.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines of Stackoverflow. Second, since this is basically a Javascript inquire head to [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and test what @sfdcfox **kindly** said, if you still can't make it work, let us know and we can discuss it further, also I suggest you to provide more details, don't be lazy when elaborating questions.